# Using Perl's File::Basename to rename a file extension

Tags: perl

Reciving the following warning message, how do I get rid of it?

`Use of uninitialized value $suffix in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/File/Basename.pm line 167.
Use of uninitialized value $suffix in substr at /usr/share/perl5/File/Basename.pm line 169.`

Code being used:

```
use File::Copy;
use File::Basename qw(fileparse);

my @mtf;
my $name;
my $dir;
my $ext;
my $ascii;
my $suffix="";

($name, $dir, $suffix) = fileparse(@mtf,qr/\.[^.]*$/);
$name =~ s/\.$suffix$//;
system("cp $mtf[0] $name.ASCII");
$ascii = "$name.ASCII";
```

Comment: What, if anything, assigns a value to `@mtf`?

Answer (score 1):

`fileparse(@mtf,qr/\.[^.]*$/);` makes no sense. Since you have to ensure that `@mtf` contains exactly one element for this to work, it makes no sense to use an array instead of a scalar.

You didn't show what `@mtf` contains, but it it's apparently not a single element, or the single element doesn't match the regexp pattern `\.[^.]*$`.